# Работа с клавиатурой PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Хотелось бы узнать существуют ли **библиотеки** или методы работы на PYTHON 3.7+ для работы, чтобы делать следующие вещи на **windows 7,8,10**: **скопировать**(ctrl +c) **вставить** (ctrl + V), сделать **скриншот** экрана(не приложения, а всего экрана), увеличить/уменьшить звук **СИСТЕМЫ**(WINDOWS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с буфером обмена я рекомедовал бы использовать встроены TK:
Запись в БО:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
c = Tk()
c.withdraw()
c.clipboard_clear()
c.clipboard_append('sample text')
c.update()
c.destroy()
```

Копирование из буфера

```
from Tkinter import Tk
c = Tk()
c.withdraw()
clip = c.clipboard_get()
c.update()
c.destroy()
print(clip)
```

Для скриншотов подходит стандартная PIL

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
screen.save('save.png','PNG')
```

Или pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))#x1 , y1, x2, y2
```

Comment: функции из TK позволят мне заменить сочетания клавиш, которые будут работать вне моего приложения? 
PS: я делаю голосовой ассистент, который по команде скопируй он нажмёт ctrl c вместо меня и тоже самое со вставкой, которая может относится не только к программе..

Comment: Нет, tk может только считывать данные из БО. Для симуляции нажатия клавиш можно использовать pyautogui

Comment: а насчёт звука тоже pyauto?

Comment: В принципе да, но если вы пишете бота, я бы порекомендовал [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/) Для нечёткого сравнения строк можно использовать difflib или написать свой алгоритм по аналогии с этим https://habr.com/ru/post/447068/